# How can i use timer in Java

Tags: java, timer

I'm reading data from serial port. The data is from IMU and I'm developing gesture recognition algorithm. I don't want to stop the whole program with Thread.sleep() method, I just need to read two sets of data 10ms apart. My application has swing GUI.

```
    float x0, x1;
    x0 = getXacc();
    x0 += 17000;
    x0 /= 1000;
    //wait 10ms
    x1 = getXacc();
    x1 += 17000;
    x1 /= 1000;
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: @PavolDudak If you want your application to not "stop" in between the variable assignments, then you should create a separate thread which can continue running while the assignments are being made.

Comment: Tell the details of your problem. Post a small compilable and runnable program that illustrates the pertinent details of your problem. I'm guessing that you might need a Swing Timer, but am frustrated by lack of relevant information about the problem space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @TimBiegeleisen answer and put his code to new Thread:

```
new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        //TimBiegeleisen code
    }
}.start();
```

Comment: I guess this is what the OP had in mind.  My answer is the best solution I can think of given the OP.

Comment: I am confused a bit too, your answer should be marked as accepted, I want only supplement this to yours, I gave you +1 @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 2):

Use `Thread.sleep()`:

```
float x0, x1;
x0 = getXacc();
x0 += 17000;
x0 /= 1000;
Thread.sleep(10);  // tell current Thread to sleep for 10 milliseconds
x1 = getXacc();
x1 += 17000;
x1 /= 1000;
```

**Note:** The Java API does not guarantee that `Thread.sleep()` will pause execution of the current Thread for *exactly* the time specified (in this case 10ms), but it will do its best to achieve this.

Comment: I can't co that. The whole program can't stop.

Comment: Who said the whole program will stop?  Any other threads in your program will continue executing.

Comment: @PavolDudak: you're not telling us the whole story, and your main question needs improvement. If you want to pause your program, yes the program will stop, but isn't that what you want? If not, please tell the rest of the story. Is this a GUI? If so tell us and tell us what kind. Details matter.

Comment: Thread.sleep() stops the current/calling thread http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long) @PavolDudak

Comment: yes I'ts GUI program, i'm reading data from serial port. the data is from IMU and i'm developing gesture recognition algorithm. i don't want to stop the whole program, i just need to read two sets of data 10ms apart.

Comment: @maskacovnik Actually, I think the stop() method was deprecated.

Comment: @PavolDudak: `"yes I'ts GUI program, i'm reading data from serial port. the data is from IMU and i'm developing gesture recognition algorithm. i don't want to stop the whole program, i just need to read two sets of data 10ms apart."` -- that's critically important information and should not be buried her in comments. Please edit your original question and give us the important details. Also, what kind of GUI? Swing? AWT? Other? Please let's avoid this frustrating game of having to drag information from you in dribs and drabs.

Comment: Sorry, I have in my mind sleep, but my fingers wrote stop :D edited @PavolDudak

Comment: One little issue. I need to use x0 and x1 data outside run method. How can i do that please.

Comment: declare float x0,x1 as private instance variables of outer class (not in annonymous class) @PavolDudak